# Respostas assíncronas do servidor, para chamadas vias AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax, json, async

Tenho uma aplicação que ao final do carregamento de uma pagina eu efetuo uma requisição AJAX que demora por volta de 20 segundos.

Após esta requisição minha pagina continua funcionando normalmente so que quando tento efetuar outra requisição AJAX ele espera a primeira retornar o resultado para depois ser executada.

Tem como executar a segunda requisição sem ter que receber o resultado da primeira?

FrontEnd

```
$.ajax({
       url: '@Url.Action("NavegarNaEscala")',
       method: 'post',
       cache: false,
       data: { escala: escala, direcao: direcao },
       success: function (data) { 
       },
       error: function () {
           ExibirMensagem(1, "Ocorreu um erro ao navegar na escala.");
       }
  });
```

BackEnd

```
 public JsonResult NavegarNaEscala(string escala, string direcao)
 {...}
```

Comment: Posta seu código, @Igor Teixeira

Comment: Pela ferramenta de desenvolvedor do navegador (F12), em Network, você consegue identificar as chamadas assíncronas e ter certeza se uma inicia após a outra ou se uma está esperando algum recurso da outra.

Answer (score 1):

Sempre utilizo Jquery em minhas requisições AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /*Primeira requisição*/
    $.ajax({...});

    /*Segunda requisição*/
    $.ajax({...});
})
```

Neste caso, nenhuma das requisições espera a outra terminar para iniciar.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /*Primeira requisição*/
    $.ajax({
        success:function(data){
            /*Segunda requisição*/
            $.ajax({...});
        }
    });
})
```

Neste caso a segunda requisição só irá iniciar após o término (com sucesso. Sem erro de comunicação com o servidor ou de má formatação do arquivo de retorno.) da primeira.

Se você não está fazendo algo parecido com isso e mesmo assim a segunda só inicia quando a primeira termina, então pode ser um caso típico de lock em recursos no banco de dados.